# Companion Object Attributes Initialization in Scala

Tags: scala, singleton

Hi I am not able to understand one thing in following program.
When i creates a new customer i gets incremented account number.
Why i am not always account number as 1002?

```
class Customer {
  private var Name: String = _
  private var AccountBalance: Int = _
  private var AccountNumber: Int = _

  def this(name: String, accountbal: Int) {
    this()
    this.Name = name
    this.AccountBalance = accountbal
    this.AccountNumber = Customer.generateAccountNumber()
  }

  def displayDetails() {
    println(s"Customer Account number is $AccountNumber \nCustomer Name is $Name \nAccount Balance is $AccountBalance")
  }
}

object Customer {
  var accountNumber = 1001

  def generateAccountNumber(): Int = {
    accountNumber += 1; accountNumber
  }
}
```

Comment: Because there is only one instance of the companion object.

Comment: Please please please, do not use **Scala** as **Java**... there is no need to have those properties as variables and a secondary constructor. Also, mutability is dangerous _(especially if you do not understand how it works)_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to understand is there is only ever a *single* instance of companion object which is shared between different instances of class, for example

```
class A {
  A.x += 1
}
object A {
  var x = 0
}

new A
new A
new A
A.x
// val res3: Int = 3
```

Here every instantiation of class `A` increments the same mutable state `x` within the same companion object `A`.